# D3 Sequence Sunburst Chart on Shiny

Tags: r, d3.js, shiny

I'm working on a project which needs to make a sequence sunburst chart. I found a sample on D3.js, but I don't know how to put it into a shiny server function. Does anyone know how to do it?

This is the link for that sunburst chart on D3: http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426

Comment: https://github.com/timelyportfolio/sunburstR/blob/master/inst/examples/example_shiny.R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should give a disclaimer that I have no idea how to use shiny.

I have a directory, `test`, with

- `server.R`
- `ui.R`
- `www/`

  - `sequences.js`
  - `sequences.css`
  - `index.html`
  - `visit-sequences.csv`

First I used this function to make the `visit-sequences.csv` file with the data

```
## function to create the csv file
make_csv <- function(x, file = '~/desktop/test/www/visit-sequences.csv') {
  dd <- data.frame(ftable(x))
  dd <- within(dd, {
    visit <- apply(dd[, -ncol(dd)], 1, function(x)
      paste0(c(x, 'end'), collapse = '-'))
    count <- dd$Freq
  })

  write.table(dd[dd$count > 0, c('visit','count')], file = file, sep = ',',
              quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
}

set.seed(1)
dd <- sample(c('home','product','search','account','other'), 500,
             replace = TRUE, prob = c(.5,.3,.1,.05,.05))
dd <- as.data.frame(matrix(dd, ncol = 5))
make_csv(dd)
```

Note that you can see the chart already without shiny

```
browseURL('~/desktop/test/www/index.html')
```

To use in a shiny app,

`server.R`

```
## server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  ## nothing here
})
```

`ui.R`

```
## ui.R
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(HTML('A sunburst chart in d3')),

  sidebarPanel(
    checkboxInput(
      inputId = 'dataSource',
      label = 'Select file.',
      value = FALSE
    ),

    conditionalPanel(
      condition = 'input.dataSource == false',
      textInput(inputId='url', label='File URL:', value='./visit-sequences.csv')
    ),

    conditionalPanel(
      condition = 'input.dataSource == true',
      fileInput(inputId = 'file', label='Data to plot:')
    )
  ),

  mainPanel(
    includeScript('./www/sequences.js'),
    includeCSS('./www/sequences.css'),
    includeHTML('./www/index.html')
  )
))
```

Finally, run

```
library('shiny')
runApp('~/desktop/test')
```

And I get this

[image]

But like I said, I don't really know what I'm doing. To change the labels, colors, and other things, you would need to edit the js, html, css files.

Comment: Thanks a lot, rawr. Since I don't have knowledge on js, html and css, I only know R, your answer helps me to understand how those three pieces make a webpage. I think I need to learn those stuff a bit first. Since my current app built by shiny has other stuff, if I just use include function to call css and js file, then those two file would be applied to the whole app (other pages). Anyway, thank again for your time. I appreciate that.